# Extract elements from a list with repeated elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, combinations

How do I get a subset of a list such that combination of a specific length occurs only once.

For eg.
a=[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]

from `a` I want to obtain something like:

```
[(1,2),[1,3,4,4,5,5]],[(1,2,3),[1,4,4,5,5],...
```

I tried using combination but the most of the results are irrelevant to the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: I just want to confirm that the expected answer is the same if I tack a 1 onto a ie `a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1]`

Comment: Hi absolutly no idea what is the desired result. can please provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

the info you gave is scarce but here's a shot from what i understood

```
a=[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
result=[]
for i in range(1,7):
    b=a.copy()
    sub_tuple=[]
    for j in range(1,i):
        x=b.pop(b.index(j))
        sub_tuple.append(x)
    result.append([tuple(sub_tuple), b])
print(result[2:])
>>> [[(1, 2), [1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]], [(1, 2, 3), [1, 4, 4, 5, 5]], [(1, 2, 3, 4), [1, 4, 5, 5]], [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), [1, 4, 5]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was actually thinking of using combinations to get that structure but there were so many values I didn't require. This definitely makes sense and serves my requirement.